# How to make gRPC request through Traefik from external network (outside docker container)?

Tags: .net, docker, devops, grpc, traefik

I implemented configuration in docker-compose file which looks like this (all containers are in a public repositories, so you can try this config by you own):

```
version: '3'

services:
  reverse-proxy:
    # The official v2.0 Traefik docker image
    image: traefik:v2.2
    # Enables the web UI and tells Traefik to listen to docker
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    depends_on:
      - ping-service
      - whoami
    ports:
      # The HTTP port
      - "80:80"
      # The Web UI (enabled by --api.insecure=true)
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      # So that Traefik can listen to the Docker events
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  whoami:
    # A container that exposes an API to show its IP address
    image: containous/whoami
    labels:
      -  "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=PathPrefix(`/foo`)"
  ping-service:
    image: deadok/vma:pingsvc1.1
    environment:
      - ms_GrpcServer__Port=80
      - ms_GrpcServer__Hostname=0.0.0.0
      - GRPC_TRACE=tcp,api,http
      - GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug
    ports:
      - "81:80"
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.services.ping-service.loadbalancer.server.scheme=h2c"
      - "traefik.http.routers.ping-service.rule=PathPrefix(`/ping`)"
  rabbit-mq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8.3-management
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=rabbitmq
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
```

In this configuration we have whoami service that serves http requests, with path prefix rule: `/foo`
And my own gRPC service written on C# (.NET Core), with route prefix rule: `/ping` .
gRPC Server implements proto contract that listed below:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.example.grpc;

option java_multiple_files = true;

enum Sentiment {
    HAPPY = 0;
    SLEEPY = 1;
    ANGRY = 2;
}

message HelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
    int32 age = 2;
    repeated string hobbies = 3;
    map<string, string> bagOfTricks = 4;
    Sentiment sentiment = 5;
}

message HelloResponse {
    string greeting = 1;
}

message GreetingEmpty {}

// 4. service, unary request/response
service GreetingService {
    rpc greeting(HelloRequest) returns (HelloResponse);
    rpc greetingNew(GreetingEmpty) returns (HelloResponse);
}
```

When I make "GET" request with the following link (in web browser for example): `http://<my.server.ip.here>/foo` everything goes fine, and i recive whoami response;

But when i tying access gRPC via C# client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.   Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://<my.server.ip.here>/ping");
    var svc = new Com.Example.Grpc.GreetingService.GreetingServiceClient(channel);
    var reply = svc.greetingNew(new Com.Example.Grpc.GreetingEmpty());
}
```

I've got an error (404, page not found). And i got same error for HTTP "GET" request using `http://<my.server.ip.here>/ping` url.

But when I make a gRPC request to exposed port 81, using url: `http://<my.server.ip.here>:81`, everything works fine.

What i am doing wrong? How can i access gRPC service through traefik outside of docker network, without SSL cert (for debugging purposes) or even with SSL?

P.S. Thank you for reading my question to the end.

Answer (score 2):

So, after a few day of "debugging" of gRPC library we discover, that gRPC client make request to url assosiated with name space in proto contract, so for my example:

```
http://<my.server.ip.here>/com.example.grpc/greetingNew
```

So we should set PathPrefix for this type of requests to PathPrefix(`/com.example.grpc`) and everything start working.